# AWS user with ReadOnlyAccess, can't describe instances in some regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

got an issue with some permissions.
I have a user with default AWS ReadOnlyAccess attached policy where is ec2:Describe*.

In some region i can describe instances, but in some i can't and getting this error.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

But without any issues i can do anything with some other client (for example iam) in the same regions where for ec2 i am getting this error.

What could restrict describing ec2 instances in some regions for the user which has ReadOnlyAccess policy?

Thnaks

Comment: Well, one example would be an SCP policy in an AWS organizations context

Comment: Which Regions are giving the error? It might be that they are 'new' regions that are turn off by default in AWS Accounts. IAM is a global service (well, it actually only runs in us-east-1), so it is not a good test of permissions. See: [Managing AWS Regions - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yep, i just understand that it IAM is bad example. So it doesn't work for the 'logs' client as well. Everything works only for one region. And i am trying to understand where it could be configured. Because user is not in the groups and user has only ReadOnlyAccess access policy attached.

Comment: Can other users (with more permissions) describe instances in the region where this read-only user gets an error?